# Run TestNG XML suite from runnable jar with test classes in specific folder

Tags: java, xml, jar, automated-tests, testng

So I have a TestNG xml file  which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Test-class Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="4" >
   <listeners>
      <listener class-name="ExtentReporterNG" />
   </listeners>
   <test name="Test-class test" allow-return-values="true">
      <classes>
         <class name="tests.TestCase1" />
         <class name="tests.TestCase2" />
         <!-- more classes -->
      </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

This test suite is started programmatically with the following java code:

```
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
List<String> testFilesList = new ArrayList<String>();
testFilesList.add("./testng.xml");
testng.setTestSuites(testFilesList);
testng.setUseDefaultListeners(false);
testng.addListener(tla); 
testng.run();
```

If I now add a new test file e.g. `TestCase3` to the package `tests` I only have to add the respective line `<class name="tests.TestCase2" />` to the xml file (this step will be automated later) and if I run my java program again the new test will also be executed.

However, if I export it as runnable jar, the test execution still works but I loose the ability to just drop new test cases in the package folder, since the `test` package obviously gets packed together with all the librarys into the .jar file and isn't represented by a folder anymore.

Is there a way to specify a path to a file in the `<class>` tag within the testng.xml file, like: `<class name="/path/to/folder/TestCaseXY" />`, so I can just drop test files in that folder and run the .jar?
If not, is there another way to accomplish this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a class path to the directory of your class file(s).

See [Setting the Class Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) for details and [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) as needed. Good luck!

Comment: Added a new class folder in the build path settings and it seems to work now. Thanks a lot!